# transform a point from pointcloud

Tags: ros, frame, transform, coordinates, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to set a goal at the side of a pointcloud. i have the x y z of the point from the pointcloud, but i need to transform it into the right frame. I went through the tf tutorials and I tried with a simple tf listener:

```
    geometry_msgs::PointStamped theGoal;
    tf::TransformListener listener;
    ros::NodeHandle node;
    ros::Rate rate(10.0);
    while (node.ok()){

     tf::StampedTransform transform;
         try{
            listener.lookupTransform("/move_base_simple/goal", "/camera/rgb/points",  ros::Time(0), transform);
         }
           catch (tf::TransformException ex){
            ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
           } 


      }
```

but now i dont know how to set the msg for move_base_simple/goal

i also tried with transformPoint, but it only works with geometry_msgs::PointStamped, i tried with transformPointCloud, but then i just get another sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 pointcloud

i just want to transform one point so i can use it to set a goal, i would even multiply it myself if someone would tell me the angles of the difference between the two frames.

i m using ubuntu 10.04, ROS electric, pcl 1.1, robot platform turtlebot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35084/transform-a-point-from-pointcloud/) by [Jerneja Mislej](https://answers.ros.org/users/2342/jerneja-mislej/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-05-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get the point out of the point cloud, construct a PointStamped, then transform it using transformPoint. Here's a code snippet that will load the values from your point into a PointStamped, transform that point into `target_frame`, and put the resulting point into `pt_transformed`.

```
geometry_msgs::PointStamped pt;
geometry_msgs::PointStamped pt_transformed;
pt.header = myCloud->header;
pt.point.x = myCloud->points[1].x;
pt.point.y = myCloud->points[1].y;
pt.point.z = myCloud->points[1].z;

tf::TransformListener listener;
listener.transformPoint("target_frame", pt, pt_transformed);
```

However, when sending a goal, whatever is listening for the goal will likely transform it into whatever frame it needs.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jerneja Mislej](https://answers.ros.org/users/2342/jerneja-mislej/) on 2012-05-28**:
right now i am getting my point by calling : myCloud -> points[1].x and same for y and z. if then i want to set the coordinates for move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal i need to correct the values myself no?

**Comment by [Jerneja Mislej](https://answers.ros.org/users/2342/jerneja-mislej/) on 2012-05-28**:
what do you mean with construct a PointStamped? do I just declare it like this? geometry_msgs::PointStamped theGoal; how can i transform my point with transformPoint if it only takes in geometry_msgs::PointStamped ?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-05-29**:
I've edited my answer with some code that will do what I described.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, this solved my problem:

```
 tf::TransformListener listener;
 tf::StampedTransform transform;
 ros::NodeHandle node;
 const std::string target_frame = "base_link";
 const std::string original_frame = "camera_rgb_optical_frame";
 const ros::Time time = ros::Time(0);
 ros::Rate rate(10.0);
 while (node.ok()){
 try{
    listener.waitForTransform(target_frame, original_frame, time, ros::Duration(10.0));
    listener.lookupTransform(target_frame, original_frame, time, transform);
    break;
  }
 catch (tf::TransformException ex){
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
 }
}

point = transform * point;
```

but when i put together the move to goal code, i realized Dan was right, in the code you can declare what ever frame you need and it works, just have to:

```
  goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "camera_rgb_optical_frame";
```

---

Originally posted by [Jerneja Mislej](https://answers.ros.org/users/2342/jerneja-mislej/) with karma: 53 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [puneet](https://answers.ros.org/users/25935/puneet/) on 2016-02-12**:
Hello Jerneja Mislej, Dan Lazewatsky

I am also doing the same thing, transformation from point of point cloud to world coordinate(/map frame). Please provide the solution(code snippet) for the tranformation.